# How to force a page to close skipping the confirmation asked by the page inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this iframe (different domain) inside my page. I have also this script that is supposed to close the page when some conditions are verified.

I encountered the problem that when the page inside the iframe changes the onbeforeunload method asking me the confirmation, the script obviously freezes wainting for a response. I tried to avoid that dialog with no success.

Is there a way to answer to the confirmation dialog automatically or to suppress it ?

Comment: The only way to suppress the confirm would be to modify the iframe's `onbeforeunload` handler. Since it's served from a different domain, you can't modify the handler, so this is not possible.

Comment: I can't skip it, ok; but isn't there a way to automatically respond that confirmation dialog?

Comment: No, there is no way to programatically respond.

Answer (score 0):

You could clean the onbeforeunload funcction with

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;

// or for the iframe

window.frames[0].onbeforeunload = null;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That won't work. The question states the iframe points to a different domain, so the Same Origin Policy would prevent it.